# Combine Sample Onsen UI Tabbar and Onsen UI Master-Detail

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui

I have added ons-list-item inside a page which is being loaded in the ons-tabbar.

Basically, I combined Sample Onsen UI Tabbar and Onsen UI Master-Detail.

However, after adding, the click behavior of Onsen UI Master-Detail is not working.

Suspecting that some change needs to be done in app.js where it is pointing like..

```
  $(document).on('pageinit', '#detail-page', function() {
$('.item-title', this).text(currentItem.title);
$('.item-desc', this).text(currentItem.desc);
$('.item-label', this).text(currentItem.label);
$('.add-note-action-item', this).click(function () {
    alert('dummy message');
});
```

});

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', '#list-page', function() {
$('.item', this).on('click', function() {
    console.log("in list-page")
  currentItem = {
    title : $('.item-title', this).text(),
    desc : $('.item-desc', this).text(),
    label : $('.item-label', this).text()
  };

  app.navi.pushPage('detail.html');
});
```

});

Comment: Could you post also the HTML or a Codepen minimum example? With just that I cannot figure out too much.

Comment: First of all  Codepen minimum example could help but for now, your jquery codes should be in `document.addEventListener("init", function (e) {})` function